# I just accidentally converted a file in Vim to all lowercase. What happened?

Tags: php, vim, smarty

There's a ton of camelCase methods and variables in this template (PHP/Smarty), and through some glitch or blunder on my part I just automagically converted them to all lowercase.  What gives?  I'm now stuck coverting all of these back to the way they were before by hand

Comment: I know that, but I've already :wq and moved to another buffer before I realized that something was amiss.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: If you've already whacked your undo history, maybe you have a recent version in source control that you can merge with?

Comment: @JoeHolloway: And if not, maybe this would be a good time to start using source control.

Comment: I have source control.  The changes aren't in a most recent commit, they were intended for the next commit.  More of an annoyance than anything, I was just curious how it happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll guess that you had a block selected in visual mode, and hit `u`. With a visual block selected `u` converts the selection to lower-case (`U` converts the selection to upper-case).

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question.  I'm pretty sure this is what happened.

Comment: this happens to me occasionally. It's odd because I use block+`=` to do the formatting, but `u` **isn't** that close. Some mental mixup with the fingers of the right hand

Answer (score 0):

By vim do you mean the unix program? If so check for the same file with a ~ after it. Emacs and vim both save the previous file.

Answer (score 0):

Press `v` and select all the parts that you wish to change case. after that press `~`, this will change the case of all selected characters.
About camleCase, you have no option than to recheck your code again.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done it if you're at the top of the file and do `guG` and generally, `gu<motion>` will lowercase everything in that motion.  Maybe even if you'd just typed `gu` and done something with the mouse maybe you got hit?